# Route with array parameter in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes

I'm currently trying to solve problem with routing in Angular 4. I want the URL to contain array of parameters, so it looks like this: `/#/WF001A;operationIds=146469,146470`. This URL was generated by Angular using [routerLink]. Parameters needs to be accessible from component (that shouldn't be a problem, I guess).

The problem is - I don't know how to create a route for it. What I tried:

- `{path: 'WF001A/:operationIds', component: WF001AComponent}`
- `{path: 'WF001A/:operationIds[]', component: WF001AComponent}`
- `{path: 'WF001A:operationIds[]', component: WF001AComponent}`
- `{path: 'WF001A;:operationIds[]', component: WF001AComponent}`

**Edit:**
This is how the link is generated:

`<a href="#" [routerLink]="['/WF001A', {operationIds:[146469, 146470]}]">test</a>`

**Edit 2:**
Component class:

```
export class WF001AComponent implements OnInit {
    public title = 'WF001A';

    public constructor (private WF001AService: WF001AService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
            // This is never executed, for route is not recognized
            let myArray=params.getAll('operationIds');
            console.log(myArray);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the routerLink parameter in your template?

Comment: Added routerLink I use in a template.

Comment: Added component snippet.

Comment: How did you solve the problem with `{path: 'WF001A:operationIds[]', component: WF001AComponent}` this kind of syntax?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I assume you have the ActivatedRoute object in your component, something like:

```
constructor(
    ...,
    private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
```

<strike>And I assume that WF001A is the parameter name,</strike> so you can do something like:

```
this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
  let i=0;
  let myArray=params.getAll('operationIds');
}
```

You can find more information about the optional parameters in the [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router#optional-route-parameters)

Comment: I think this does not solve the problem. I get this error in console: `Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'WF001A;operationIds=146469,146470'`, which implies that route is not prepared for array.

Comment: I tried to use your example, but unfortunately it is never executed, because Angular actually does not know any route that matches `WF001A;operationIds=146469,146470` or `WF001A/operationIds=146469,146470`. However, you were right about the processing part and after sending parameters like this: `WF001A/146469,146470`, I have been able to get those data.

Comment: Not sure how to resolve this question, as this was partially fault of the way of serializing those parameters, but I think you actually deserve your answer to be accepted as it kicked me the right way :)